# Assistance with calls to a function and the placement of the result a specific location based on the statement that called it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not a web developer but am enjoying working with jQuery on a timesheet form i am creating for my employer's specific needs.

I am working on part of the timesheet that takes the Start Time and Finish Time along with the Meal Break start and finish time and calculates the total hours worked. This works well using examples found on stack overflow and modifications to meet my needs. Below is the code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ){
     function calculate() {

         var StartTime = jQ(".form-group .StartTime").val().split(':'), 
             FinishTime = jQ(".form-group .FinishTime").val().split(':'),
             MealStart = jQ(".form-group .MealStart").val().split(':'),
             MealFinish = jQ(".form-group .MealFinish").val().split(':');
         
         var StartHour = parseInt(StartTime[0], 10) || 0,
             FinishHour = parseInt(FinishTime[0], 10) || 0,
             StartMin = parseInt(StartTime[1], 10) || 0,
             FinishMin = parseInt(FinishTime[1], 10) || 0,
             MealStartHour = parseInt(MealStart[0], 10) || 0,
             MealFinishHour = parseInt(MealFinish[0], 10)|| 0,
             MealStartMins = parseInt(MealStart[1], 10) || 0,
             MealFinishMins = parseInt(MealFinish[1], 10) || 0;
         
         var CalcHours = FinishHour - StartHour, 
             CalcMins = 0,
             MealHours = MealFinishHour - MealStartHour, 
             MealMins = 0;
         
         if(CalcHours < 0) CalcHours = 24 + CalcHours;
          
         if(FinishMin >= StartMin) {
                CalcMins = FinishMin - StartMin;
         }
            else {
             CalcMins = (FinishMin + 60) - StartMin;
             CalcHours--;
         }

         CalcMins = CalcMins / 60;
               
         CalcHours += CalcMins;
                
         CalcHours = CalcHours.toFixed(2);
         
         if(MealHours < 0) MealHours = 24 + MealHours;
            if(MealFinishMins >= MealStartMins) {
             MealMins = MealFinishMins - MealStartMins;
         }
         else {
             MealMins = (MealFinishMins + 60) - MealStartMins;
             MealHours--;
         }
         MealMins = MealMins / 60; 
         MealHours += MealMins;
         MealHours = MealHours.toFixed(2);
         
         GrandTotal = CalcHours - MealHours;
//Convert to fixed decimal again
         GrandTotal = GrandTotal.toFixed(2);
//Display the total in the correct location on the page
  jQ(".Hours").val(GrandTotal);
     }

})
```

i wrote the code as a function as there are 20 locations on the form that the value of the variable Grand_Total will be placed based on the event that triggers the function.e.g an on change event for Wednesday should only update the total field for Wednesday

My first issue is the value assigned to Grand_Total is not available outside the function even though it is not defined as variable, i was of the opinion that if i omitted the var in front of

```js
    GrandTotal = CalcHours - MealHours;
```

that this would make it global and available anywhere. I am assuming the variable needs to be global so i can call on it from different events

My second issue is i am trying not to duplicate the code for every change in location where the value needs to be stored so my question is what is the best way to run event actions like the following to place the grand total where its needed without affecting the totals in other input boxes

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ){
      jQ('#Wed1_StartTime','#Wed1_FinishTime','#Wed1_MealStart','#Wed1_MealFinish').change(function(){
        jQ('.Hours').val("Grand_Total");
        
// i want to place the value in the input box with a class of .Hours for Wed 1 fieldset only
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ){
      jQ('#Thur1_StartTime','#Thur1_FinishTime','#Thur1_MealStart','#Thur1_MealFinish').change(function(){
        jQ('.Hours').val("Grand_Total");
        
// i want to place the value in the input box with a class of .Hours for Thurq fieldset only
        
//etc
```

As you can see this will not work as the same value will be input into all input boxes regardless of the fieldset being modified as all total fields have the same class name. Using ID's i feel is bad coding as i would have write 20 versions of the function and call each one individually based on the elements being changed.

Hope this makes sense

Thanks in advance for any help offered

Comment: I have posted my answer let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing out couple of issues from your code and assumptions, Firstly

> My first issue is the value assigned to Grand_Total is not available outside the function even though it is not defined as variable, i was of the opinion that if i omitted the var in front of that this would make it global and available anywhere.

NO, this assumption is wrong, The variable will be global only when placed in global scope. Explaining your code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ){ //<-- note this block 
  function calculate() {
   // your other code
    GrandTotal = CalcHours - MealHours; // you assume this must be global varialbe only because there is no var in front of it.
  }
})
```

The variable scope is within the block, And as you assume it should be global, Yes it is global `But global within in block`. Its available to all the functions and code with in the block only.

Now how to create a global variable.

1) Placing the variable declaration under script block and not under any function block. hence available for all the scripts.

```
 <script>
        var GrandTotal; //<-- this is global, as its placed directly under script tag and not contained inside any block.
        jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ){
              function calculate() {
               // your other code
                GrandTotal = CalcHours - MealHours; 
              }
            })
    </script>
```

2) using `window` scope while declaring the variable. This will place the variable into the window scope, and is global.

```
<script>           
        jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ){
              function calculate() {
               // your other code
                window.GrandTotal = CalcHours - MealHours; // note the window.GrandTotal
              }
            })
    </script>
```

> My second issue is i am trying not to duplicate the code for every change in location where the value needs to be stored so my question is what is the best way to run event actions like the following to place the grand total where its needed without affecting the totals in other input boxes

Since you have not posted any HTML, I will give m best to answer close to your HTML, you can change it to stuff that works for you.

To write a common Jquery you must use class selectors. When ever we write code to work generic way then `class is the best choice`. So put a class to all your input elements to which you want to bind the change event, Also give a class name to all your div's which holds the input elements of each day. Something like this

```
<div class="DayTimeWrapper"> 
    <input id="Wed1_StartTime" class="setTime" />
    <input id="Wed1_FinishTime" class="setTime" />
    <input id="Wed1_MealStart" class="setTime" />
    <input id="Wed1_MealFinish" class="setTime" />
    <input class="Hours" />
</div>
<div class="DayTimeWrapper">
    <input id="Thur1_StartTime" class="setTime" />
    <input id="Thur1_FinishTime" class="setTime" />
    <input id="Thur1_MealStart" class="setTime" />
    <input id="Thur1_MealFinish" class="setTime" />
    <input class="Hours" />
</div>
```

Now your Jquery would be as simple as below.

```
 jQ('.setTime').change(function(){ // set event to all the elements at once with class name setTime
        jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').val(Grand_Total);
    });
```

`jQ(this).closest('.DayTimeWrapper').find('.Hours').val(Grand_Total);` : here `jQ(this)` means the element which triggered the change event. Now find the closest div with class `DayTimeWrapper` that would be the div which hold this element. Now trace down to find the input with class `Hours` within this div and set the value.

So this way we can bind events to all the elements with this simple code, Also the hours will be updated for that particular day itself.

let me know if this helps and if you want further help.

**EDIT 1:** Adding the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/g4eucpL5/10/) which is the modified version of yours

Comment: This does help but i cant seem to get it too work. Not sure if its because of the html generated by the app that creates the form. I have added a fiddle with the generated html and code with you suggestions, can you look and see where i am going wrong https://jsfiddle.net/AUser3966/g4eucpL5/8/

Comment: Not all your input tags have the class `setTime` in it.  I had to put the class to all the missing inputs and tweek some of your logic. Here's the working Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/g4eucpL5/10/ Let me know if this helps

Comment: I didnt add the seTime to all input tags by design as i only wanted to run the calculation when the FinishTime and mealFinish times were entered. That being said your change in logic works perfectly. Thanks for the assistance